# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a website using the google maps javascript API to find hotels around a city, and compare the distances between each hotel to user-entered locations in order to find the hotel closest to all the locations they want to visit.

First it calculates the coordinates of the user-entered locations (using the geocoding API which works fine), and then it gets the coordinates/google places information of the hotels.

Using the google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(LatLng a, LatLng b); to get the distance between each hotel and the user-entered addresses, the function returns this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined**

However, both of the LatLng arguments I pass to the function don't seem to be null or undefined.

Each of the if(location1 != ""), if(location2 != ""), etc. code blocks checks if the LatLng objects for either the hotel or the location is null and prints an error if it is, but these errors are **not** printed in the javascript console when i run the webpage.

Here is the Javascript and HTML in question:

```js
   
   var map;
   var infowindow;

   function initMap() {
    var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
     });


     infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

   }

   

   function createMarker(place) {
     var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
     });
   }
   var nearbyHotels = [];
   var cityCoordinates;
   var cityCoordinatesLatLng;
   function findHotels()
   {
    
    var nearbyHotelsLat = [];
    var nearbyHotelsLong = [];
    
    var locationScores1 = [];
    var locationScores2 = [];
    var locationScores3 = [];
    var locationScores4 = [];
    var locationScores5 = [];
    
    var avgScores = [];

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var cityAddress = document.getElementById('locations_cityField').value;
    var radiusSearch = parseInt(document.getElementById('locations_rangeField').value);
    
    var location1 = document.getElementById('locations_location1').value;
    var location2 = document.getElementById('locations_location2').value;
    var location3 = document.getElementById('locations_location3').value;
    var location4 = document.getElementById('locations_location4').value;
    var location5 = document.getElementById('locations_location5').value;
    
    var location1LatLng;
    var location2LatLng;
    var location3LatLng;
    var location4LatLng;
    var location5LatLng;
    
    if(location1 != "" && location1 != undefined)
     location1LatLng = geocodeAddress(geocoder, location1);
     
    if(location2 != "" && location2 != undefined)
     location2LatLng = geocodeAddress(geocoder, location2);
     
    if(location3 != "" && location3 != undefined)
     location3LatLng = geocodeAddress(geocoder, location3);
    
    if(location4 != "" && location4 != undefined)
     location4LatLng = geocodeAddress(geocoder, location4);
     
    if(location5 != "" && location5 != undefined)
     location5LatLng = geocodeAddress(geocoder, location5);

    console.log(location1LatLng);
    
    var cityLoc = geocodeAddress(geocoder, cityAddress);
    setTimeout(function(){
    
     
     var coordSplit = cityCoordinates.split(",");
     
     var lati = parseFloat(coordSplit[0]);
     var lngi = parseFloat(coordSplit[1]);
     
     var city = {lat: lati, lng: lngi};
     
     var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
       service.nearbySearch({
      location: city,
      radius: radiusSearch,
      types: ['lodging']
       }, callback);
       
     map.setCenter(cityLoc);
     setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("nearbyHotels.length: " + nearbyHotels.length);
      if(location1 != "")
      {
       for(var i = 0; i < nearbyHotels.length; i++)
       {
       
        var hotelLatLng = nearbyHotels[i].geometry.location;
        
        if(location1LatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL LOCATION1LATLNG");
        }
        if(hotelLatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL (1) HOTELLATLNG");
        }
        var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location1LatLng, hotelLatLng);
        locationScores1.push(dist);
       }
      }
      if(location2 != "")
      {
       for(var i = 0; i < nearbyHotels.length; i++)
       {
        var hotelLatLng = nearbyHotels[i].geometry.location;
        if(location2LatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL LOCATION2LATLNG");
        }
        if(hotelLatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL (2) HOTELLATLNG");
        }
        var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location2LatLng, hotelLatLng);
        locationScores2.push(dist);
       }
      }
      if(location3 != "")
      {
       for(var i = 0; i < nearbyHotels.length; i++)
       {
        var hotelLatLng = nearbyHotels[i].geometry.location;
        if(location3LatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL LOCATION3LATLNG");
        }
        if(hotelLatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL (3) HOTELLATLNG");
        }
        var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location3LatLng, hotelLatLng);
        locationScores3.push(dist);
       }
      }
      if(location4 != "")
      {
       for(var i = 0; i < nearbyHotels.length; i++)
       {
        var hotelLatLng = nearbyHotels[i].geometry.location;
        if(location4LatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL LOCATION4LATLNG");
        }
        if(hotelLatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL (4) HOTELLATLNG");
        }
        var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location4LatLng, hotelLatLng);
        locationScores4.push(dist);
       }
      }
      if(location5 != "")
      {
       for(var i = 0; i < nearbyHotels.length; i++)
       {
        var hotelLatLng = nearbyHotels[i].geometry.location;
        if(location5LatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL LOCATION5LATLNG");
        }
        if(hotelLatLng == "")
        {
         console.log("NULL (5) HOTELLATLNG");
        }
        var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(location5LatLng, hotelLatLng);
        locationScores5.push(dist);
       }
      }
      
      for(var i = 0; i < nearbyHotels.length; i++)
      {
       var avgDist;
       var numLocations = 0;
       
       if(location1 != "")
       {
        numLocations++;
        avgDist += locationScores1[i];
       }
       if(location2 != "")
       {
        numLocations++;
        avgDist += locationScores2[i];
       }
       if(location3 != "")
       {
        numLocations++;
        avgDist += locationScores3[i];
       }
       if(location4 != "")
       {
        numLocations++;
        avgDist += locationScores4[i];
       }
       if(location5 != "")
       {
        numLocations++;
        avgDist += locationScores5[i];
       }
       
       avgDist = avgDist / numLocations;
       
       avgScores.push(avgDist);
       
       
       
      }
      var avgScoresSorted = avgScores.sort(function (a, b) { 
        return b - a;
       });
       
       
      for(var i = 0; i < avgScoresSorted.length; i++)
      {
       var index = avgScores.indexOf(avgScoresSorted[i]);
       var hotelName = nearbyHotels[index].name;
       var hotelAddress = nearbyHotels[index].vicinity;
       document.getElementById("displayHotelsDiv").innerHTML += (i + 1) + ": " + hotelName + " (" + hotelAddress + ") - LocationScore: " + avgScoresSorted[i];
      }
     }, 10000);
     
    }, 5000);
    
    
         
   }
   
   function callback(results, status) {
     if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      console.log(results[i]);
      createMarker(results[i]);
      nearbyHotels.push(results[i]);
    }
     }
   }
   
   function initSearchButtonListener()
   {
    
    
    document.getElementById('button_searchhotels').addEventListener('click', function() {
     findHotels();
      });
      
    initMap();
   }
   
   
   function geocodeAddress(geocoder, address) {
    console.log("address " + address);
    console.log("geocoder " + geocoder);
     geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     var coords = results[0].geometry.location.toString();
     console.log("CoordsRaw: " + coords)
     var coordsNoFirst = coords.substring(1);
     var coordsNoLast = coordsNoFirst.slice(0, -1);
     cityCoordinates = coordsNoLast;
     console.log(cityCoordinates);
     
     return results[0].geometry.location;
     
    } else {
      alert('Could not convert an address to latitude/longitude for the google maps API: ' + status);
    }
     });
   }
```

And the html that goes along with it:

```html
<div class="container" id="locations">
       <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_location1" placeholder="Enter address of the 1st location">
        </div>
          
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_location2" placeholder="Enter address of the 2nd location">
        </div>
         
       </div>
       <br></br>
       <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_location3" placeholder="Enter address of the 3rd location">
        </div>
          
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_location4" placeholder="Enter address of the 4th location">
        </div>
         
       </div>
       <br></br>
       <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
          
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_location5" placeholder="Enter address of the 5th location">
        </div>
         
       </div>
       <br></br>
    <div class="row">
     <div id="locationField">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_cityField" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" />
        </div>
     <div id="rangeField">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locations_rangeField" placeholder="Enter a search radius in meters (from the city center)" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center">
     <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>    
    </div>
       <button id="button_searchhotels" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Search</button>



<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVVnR7yKErwMDd6yC-GzVpRXFvNTtoKhQ&signed_in=true&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initSearchButtonListener"
          async defer></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you could point us to where exactly in the 300 lines of code the error occurs ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return anything from its callback function. You have to *use* the data inside the callback function when/where it is available.  Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

This is incorrect:

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, address) {
  console.log("address " + address);
  console.log("geocoder " + geocoder);
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var coords = results[0].geometry.location.toString();
      console.log("CoordsRaw: " + coords)
      var coordsNoFirst = coords.substring(1);
      var coordsNoLast = coordsNoFirst.slice(0, -1);
      cityCoordinates = coordsNoLast;
      console.log(cityCoordinates);

      //*********** this will not do anything useful **********
      return results[0].geometry.location;
      //*******************************************************

    } else {
      alert('Could not convert an address to latitude/longitude for the google maps API: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```